# Unable to find any CM login information in Sitecore 10.1

Tags: azure, logging, login, azure-ad

I cannot find any login messages in my `Azure application insights`.
Only found a logout message like this:
`AUDIT (sitecore\foo.bar): Logout: sitecore\foo.bar.`

Does anyone know where to find the login message?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Identity Server for CM authentication, then you will not get audit log for Login as Identity Server does not do AUDIT log by default. `AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Login`.

If you [disable the Identity Server](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/understanding-sitecore-authentication-behavior-changes.html#disable-sitecore-identity) and try to login, you will get the Audit log for Login as the authentication is happening in the CM itself.

If you would like to get AUDIT log for login, you may need to check the Identity server log configuration.

Comment: I cannot find any login information in my Identity Server sts-2021XXXX.log.